# Does polling block other operations in LinkedBlockingQueue?

Tags: java, multithreading, blockingqueue

In the pseudocode below I have a `poll()` function that gets called forever in the main thread. When I do this without the `sleep()` statement in `poll()`, only 2-3 items a minute get added to the queue by the other thread. Does this mean that polling blocks the `put()` statement?

How can I solve this problem?

```
public class Test extends Thread{
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Object> queue = null;

    Test(){
        queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Object>(10);
    }

    public void run(){
        // Do stuff, get incoming object from network
        queue.put(o);
    }

    public Object poll(){
        Object o = queue.poll();
        sleep(1000);
        return o;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Does this mean that polling blocks the put() statement?

No, `LinkedBlockingQueue` is fully reentrant and the `poll()` method does not block the `put()`.  However, the `poll()` method returns immediately.  You probably should be using `queue.take()` which waits for there to be an item in the queue instead of returning null if the queue is empty.

```
// wait for there to be an object in the queue
Object o = queue.take();
// no sleep necessary
return o;
```

Since you are constructing a constrained blocking queue of 10 entries, I guess that main is blocking on the `sleep()` and the queue then fills up and slows down your program.  You maybe should only `sleep` if there `poll()` returns `null` and sleep for a shorter amount of time.

**Edit:** As @JohnVint mentioned in the comments, another alternative is to use the `poll(long, TimeUnit)` method which will wait for an item to be added to the queue for the time period and returns `null` if the timer expires.  That is a cleaner way to wait for something in the queue.

```
// wait for 1000ms for there to be an object in the queue
Object o = queue.poll(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
// no sleep necessary
return o;
```

Comment: Yes, that was my first idea. But if I use take(), my mainthread is blocked if my queue is empty. I want to do some other stuff in that thread also.

Comment: @fibera Take a look at `public E poll(long timeout,              TimeUnit unit)   throws InterruptedException` for that functionality then.  Cleaner and more correct then `sleep`ing.

Comment: John is right about the `poll(timout, unit)` of course.  You could also only sleep if `(o == null)` and significantly reduce the sleep amount to 10 or 20ms.

Comment: @John Ok tyvm guys. I'm going to look at poll(timeout, unit).